# Sitecore Layout File Name Returned

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sitecore

I'm trying to obtain the name of the web page in the address bar URL from a website developed with Sitecore.

```
http://localhost:52543/About/AboutUs.aspx
```

Instead of returning what I expected to be "AboutUs.aspx", my code returns the Sitecore layout control file name: "BrowserFixedLaout.aspx".

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim test As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.ToString())
```

How do you achieve this when working with Sitecore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the name of the page (item) in Sitecore, you can use

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Name
```

if you want to get the /AboutUs.aspx only, you can use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
```

and take the part after last / only

Comment: or HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl if you also need the querystring.

Comment: The HttpContext.Current.Request.Path still returned the layout name. Ended up using the Sitecore.Context.Item.Name. Thanks!